# Rails Best Practice: Constants for model ids, or find_by or where queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a situation where I need to make a best practice decision which will affect a large part of my system. There are many different `has_many through:` relationships that I will be querying often to see if a specific item exists and is attached to another item.

```
class User
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end

class Skill
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end

class UserSkill
    belongs_to :skill
    belongs_to :user
end
```

There will be thousands of `users` in the system that can be combined with any amount of `skills`, of which there are about 200+. I'm trying to figure out what is the fastest, most efficient way to query a `user` to find out if he/she possesses a specific `skill`. I'm leaning toward Constants because the IDs will obviously be different in dev, test, and production, and it would be nice to only have to load them up once instead of searching for a non-indexed name every time.

**1. #find_by (:name)**

```
@user.skills.find_by(name: 'Ruby-on-Rails').present?
```

**2. #where ('name...')**

```
@user.skills.where("name = 'Ruby-on_rails'").present?
```

**3. Constant + #find_by (:id)**
*constants would be set dynamically on application load using `#const_set` so there would be over 200 constants always stored*

```
RUBY_ON_RAILS = 41
RUBY = 42
PHP = 45

@user.skills.find_by(id: RUBY_ON_RAILS).present?
```

**4. Constant + #pluck (:id)**
*same constants as above*

```
@user.skills.pluck(:id).include?(RUBY_ON_RAILS)
```

**5. ???**
*any better way that I have't thought of*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do this:

```
@user.skills.exists?(name: 'Ruby-on-Rails')
```

It also works on a relation:

```
@user.skills.where(name: 'Ruby-on-Rails').exists?
```

Answer (score 1):

For best practice on topic 1, don't use "find_by".  Scopes are the way to go:

```
class Skill
  scope :names, ->(*n) {  #I always use plural form in my scopes
    where(name: n.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }

end

Skill.names("ruby-on-rails").exist? 
Skill.names("ruby-on-rails").any? 
Skill.names("ruby-on-rails").present?
```

Edit: Typo

Comment: `any?` and `present?` will select all the values from the database, just to check if there are some

Comment: Actually, they all will cause a db hit.

Comment: But there is a slight difference between selecting all records from the table, and selecting the count :)